# Android setLayoutDirection on DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, dialog, right-to-left, dialogfragment

I've recently finished building a project, and my next goal was to create a build flavor specially for RTL, one important note was that I need to force the RTL layout, independent from the device language.

So I managed to force RTL on most of the app using the view method **setLayoutDirection** and rotated all the views that didn't cooperate , but for some reason, I couldn't mirror the dialogs in the app, which appear to flip only when the device language change. 
I tried to flip the dialog in the onCreateDialog, accessing getView, which returned null, and I'm not sure what else I can do ...

Could someone help me flip the DialogFragment to RTL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection()`for `AlartDialog`, The layout Direction will change for title and content but not for the buttons.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    // Here you can change the layout direction via setLayoutDirection()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }

    return alertDialog;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to change it for the buttons as well?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes. You can ask it in separate post.